# only list attributes defined in the constructor of the class?

Tags: python, uml

i was thinking, that in a class-diagram in UML in which you create a class, and specify its attributes, you only define all the attributes of the class, which can/shall be found in the constructor-method of the class.
when i tried reverse engineering on my (python-)code with visual paradigm, every attribute was shown in the generated classes(those declared in the constructor and those declared in other methods of the class).

I would like to think, that this is a mistake by visual paradigm.

can someone please tell me, if i was wrong in my assumption, or if the VP-code-generator is wrong. thanks in advance.

Comment: List of class attributes and list of arguments passed to class constructor are completely independent concepts. For instance some languages (C++, TypeScript, ...) automatically assume empty implicit constructor with 0 arguments if the programmer does not say otherwise. See also http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams-overview.html. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: thanks, i am still reading that link.but i did not mean arguments passed to the class constructor. i mean the attributes i create "myself" in the constructor method. i thought, that i only write these in the attributes-compartment of a class in uml. or does the compartment also have to contain every attribute of the class that i might create within different methods of the class.

Comment: Add your python code to the question and screenshot of the VP-generated class diagrams to illustrate your problem more tangibly. All attributes the class will ever use/have (regardless of when exactly they appear at run-time) should be in the attribute compartment. The UML Class Diagram is supposed to represent static immutable view of the class structure. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Thank you, xmojmr. I think, your last comment is exactly the answer, that i was looking for. You could post that as the answer(beginning with the second sentence).

Comment: In hindsight, that was a stupid question. I somehow did not see in that moment, that every "variable" is an object of a class, even if its one of the primitive datatypes. so they have to be treated just like other compositions or aggregations of classes.

Comment: I've posted the comment as answer and added some links. In hindsight I think this question is not stupid if you add the `python` tag. For example the problem of reverse engineering existing `JavaScript` code into the `UML` view of the world also does not have an easy answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** Visual Paradigm's reverse engineering automaton seems alright in this regard.

---

> [Sparx Systems → UML 2 Tutorial → Class Diagram](http://www.sparxsystems.com/resources/uml2_tutorial/uml2_classdiagram.html)
>
> **Class Diagrams**
>
> The class diagram shows the building blocks of any object-orientated system. Class diagrams depict a static view of the model, or part of the model, describing what attributes and behavior it has rather than detailing the methods for achieving operations. Class diagrams are most useful in illustrating relationships between classes and interfaces. Generalizations, aggregations, and associations are all valuable in reflecting inheritance, composition or usage, and connections respectively...

In the context of properties created dynamically by `Python` code at runtime my translation would be that all attributes the class will ever use/have (regardless of when exactly they appear at run-time) should be in the attribute compartment.

The `UML Class Diagram` is supposed to represent **static immutable** ("compile-time") view of the **greatest possible memory structure** (composed of blocks called classes) and falls into the [UML Structure Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#structure-diagram) category.

**If** you want to document (the `UML`-way) **when** some attributes receive a well-defined value at runtime **then** you'd need to use some of the diagrams falling into the [UML Behavior Diagrams](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html#behavior-diagram) category.

The `UML` class model can be turned into a computer-executable model in some languages (e.g. `JavaScript`) in a very dynamic and polymorphic way. That's only an implementation concern, something that the `UML` does not really care about too much. What `UML` cares about is mostly the [Platform-independent model (PIM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform-independent_model).

Comment: thanks for answering. but you would only list one attribute in the attribute-compartement of the class if you don't already have a composition drawn between the class and the other class which is the type of the respective attribute, right?. i mean, for each attribute, you have to choose between listing it in the attribute-compartment and drawing an association, is that correct?

Comment: @coffeekid you can show it as an attribute or a link or both. This http://stackoverflow.com/a/27216132/2626313 seems relevant. What really matters is if in the UML model (the invisible thing that the tool uses as the "backend" and that can be round-tripped into another UML-compliant tool in the [XML Metadata Interchange (*.xmi)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_Metadata_Interchange) format) the associations are modeled correctly. I sometimes use the tools code generation feature to look at the model from the source code point of view. Java code generators are often quite close

Comment: thank you again. the last hint in your comment was very helpful too. :-) just to avoid confusion, i have to add to this, that you would not call it link. because a link is the instance of an association. so, an association connects two classes and a link would be a connection between two objects.